# How to select text on onClick event of pie chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Here is my plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/qJnZzBS4ZOUtD2q9FV11?p=preview

Each `.nv-slice` looks like

```
<g class="nv-slice" fill="#ff7f0e" stroke="#ff7f0e"><path d="M-127.70778813276479,57.36480497863532A140,140 0 0,1
```

-2.5716733430269922e-14,-140L0,0Z">Travel

**Problem**
How when I click on `.nv-slice`, I get the value of `text` inside the `.nv-slice` clicked?

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-slice')
      .on('click', function(){
        alert('click - ' ); // how can I search for text inside this .nv-slice?
      });
```

Thank you

Comment: nope, it doesn't get me anything :(

Comment: Ok, little bit more complex -- `this.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Lars comment, I tried and get the following to work

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-slice')
      .on('click', function(){
        console.log('hello - ', this.getElementsByClassName("nv-label")[0].textContent);
      });
```

Thank you @Lars!

Comment: There is another solution, if you use [pie.js](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/pie.js) from nvd3, 'line 109' also allows you to get the data of the pie chart slice you clicked.